# What does "gone amok" mean in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

> Clutter is political correctness gone amok. (In *"[On Writing Well](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53343.On_Writing_Well)"*)

Is there any grammar rule with "gone" in this sentence or is it just an idiom with "amok"?

Thank you

Comment: It's a past-participial clause serving as a postpositive adjective to the noun phrase "political correctness". (**Go** - **went** (past form) - **gone** (past participle).) The original form is "**to go amok**", like "to go crazy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Clutter is political correctness **gone amok**.

No, this use of **gone** is not limited to **amok**. This construction follows the same pattern as **gone crazy**, and often carries the same overall meaning:

> Clutter is political correctness **gone crazy**.

There's also **go nuts**:

> Clutter is political correctness **gone nuts**.

Or **gone wild**

> Clutter is political correctness **gone wild**.

---

The original idiom for **amok** was "**[running amok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_amok)**". The phrase described "an episode of sudden mass assault against people or objects usually by a single individual following a period of brooding" (Wikipedia). In "to run amok", the word "amok" is an adverb.

---

**Gone** is the past-participle form of **to go**, and **amok** serves as an adjective. Together, they modify the noun phrase "political correctness".

Thus, we have "political correctness that has become crazy".

Comment: Can I ask one more question? Why "gone" to be used here instead of "to go"?

Comment: @user152424 -- "Clutter is political correctness *to go amok* In "On Writting Well" -- this would be a strange sentence, and it will lose the original meaning. **To go amok** cannot serve as a description of **political correctness**.

Comment: Fun Fact: Many speakers of American English are unaware that this word is spelled *amok* and might even say it is a misspelling of *amuck*. Examples of *[gone amuck](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gone%20amuck%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)*. See *amuck* in [One Look dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=amuck&ls=a). The spellings are variant spellings.

Comment: It's "gone" because it's in the past tense: The political correctness **has gone** amok.  "Clutter is political correctness to go amok" doesn't make any sense.